# Cycloid angular parameter solution to an ODE for density fluctuations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, parametric, cycloid

I'm just reading over some Cosmology notes and there is a little ODE solve that I am not quite understanding.

I have an equation of the form:

$$
\ddot{R}=-\frac{GM}{R^{2}}
$$

Integrating gives:

$$
\dot{R}^{2}=+\frac{2GM}{R}+\mathcal{E}
$$

Where $\mathcal{E}$ is just a constant of integration. The notes are essentially saying that this can be solved with a parameter $\theta$ such that r is given by:

$$
r(\theta)=R_{0}(1-\cos\theta)
$$

In terms of density this can be written as:

$$
\dot{R}^{2}=\frac{4\pi{G}}{3}\rho_{0}R^{2}
$$

There is also a solution of the form:

$$
\rho(\theta)=\rho_{0}\frac{9(\theta-\sin\theta)^{2}}{2(1-\cos\theta)^{3}}
$$

Could anyone run through exactly how this is come about?

Comment: i guess u mean $R(\theta)$. Furthermore the dots refer to a derivative in t?

Comment: Yes and yes. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordinary Differential Equations used in Cosmology](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548614/ordinary-differential-equations-used-in-cosmology)

Comment: @FritsVeerman This is a new question for density cycloid which was not discussed in the above question.

Comment: Are you sure the right hand side of your ODE involving $\dot{R}$ and $\rho_0$ is linear in $R$, and not quadratic in $R$?

Comment: Yes. The density term will introduce radial extent, but when density is included the equation is linear.

Comment: Could you maybe include in your question the precise way the equation $\dot{R}^2 \sim \frac{1}{R}$ is transformed into the equation $\dot{R}^2 \sim R$? So, how exactly the equation can be rewritten in terms of density? This would clarify a couple of things, at least for me.

Comment: @FritsVeerman You were in fact right, after integrating you obtain $R^{2}$ on the RHS. I apologise.